# Publish framework dependant with third party dll

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04

When I publish my asp.net core app to my linux server as framework dependant I get this error:

```
root@ns559571:~# dotnet /var/www/project/publish/project.dll
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (project.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'NLog.Extensions.Logging', version: '1.2.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll'
```

On my server I have the latest .net core 2.1 sdk and runtime and my project targets 2.1 but I notice these messages reference 2.0.

When I publish is as self contained it runs, however its around 600 files to sync so I'd rather do framework dependant.

Is there a way to publish framework dependant but get the third party dll aslo?

I tried `dotnet restore`in the publish directory on server and it gives me this message:

> error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid

Do I also need to install 2.0 on server?  I went to microsoft site but couldn't find the Ubuntu package name for 2.0, only the latest instructions for 2.1.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520180/862795

Comment: I already have sdk instlled.  I am referring to nuget packages when publishing